# Liberar Input ao clicar em Select

Tags: php, select

Olá,
Estou com uma dúvida em meu código.
Preciso que ao clicar em um Select seja exibido campos para cadastros.
Por exemplo:

```
 <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">                                    
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Produto</label>
          <div class="col-md-3">                                        
           <select class="form-control select" name="tipo">
                  <option>Carro</option>
                  <option>Moto</option>
                  <option>Jetski</option>
                  <option>Barco</option>
           </select>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Ao selecionar Carro, por exemplo, abra estes campos:

```
    <div class="col-md-6" nome"carro">                        
                        <div class="block">
                            <h4>Opcionais</h4>
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">                                    
                                        <label class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="airbag" class="icheckbox"/> Airbag</label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-4">   
                                        <label class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="freio_a_disco" class="icheckbox"/> Freio a disco</label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-4">   
                                        <label class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="abs" class="icheckbox"/> ABS</label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-4">   
                                        <label class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="cambio_manual" class="icheckbox"/> Câmbio manual</label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-4">   
                                        <label class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="cambio_automatico" class="icheckbox"/> Câmbio automático</label>
                                        </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                </div>
```

Vou fazer os campos Checkbox para cada Tipo (categoria do select), para motos, casas, carros, etc.
Minha dúvida é como insiro o conjunto todo ao clicar no Select.

Comment: Minha resposta te ajudou? Se sim, marque ela como aceita :)

Comment: Olá Diego,
Funcionou, muito obrigado!

Comment: Então pode aceitar minha resposta abaixo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar adaptar o Ajax abaixo para isso. Lembre se por id e name nos campos:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#div_para_ocultar").hide()
     $('#tipo').on('change',function(){
         if( $(this).val()==="Carro"){
            $("#div_para_ocultar").show()
         } else if... {
            $("#div_para_ocultar_2").show()
        }
    });
});
</script>
```